# Monitoring unit test that runs in CI

Tags: c#, unit-testing, continuous-integration, monitoring, xunit.net

I want to monitor xunit.net tests that are running in CI (if you know similar approaches for nunit it may also helps).

Integration tests that were running double in time and I would like to get information like methods call timing and resources usage.

I started windows performance monitor but it isnt clear to me where the time is being spent inside the test and why it double in execution.

Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For a high-tech option that might cost you a few dollars, look into a profiling tool.  there is a really good one for dotnet called ANTS Performance Profiler that can help you work out where some of your bottlenecks are. It will also link to your code to show you exactly where the problems are showing up.

The simplest free (as in only spending your time) approach that I can think of is to introduce a base test class, and use the setup/teardown methods to log timing and other information to either console or file. Alternately you could create a test harness for use within each of your tests, and add the logging there. A slightly more sophisticated approach would be to use some method of delegation to trigger the Assign/Act/Assert stages of your tests, and apply your logging there. Personally, I do all of my C# testing using a product called StoryQ.  If I needed something logged, I would introduce a few extension methods to effectively wrapper my logging while still behaving as test steps.

If it were me though, I'd spend the bucks and choose the profiler.  It will pay for itself time and again, and really helps you to determine where to invest your time optimizing your code.

Comment: The issue with unit test on CI was related to hardware failure, I started taking a look at ants performance profiler and seems like a good tool, thanks for your suggestion.